Why is the potential of a pendulum $mgh$?
In all pendulum examples I've (assuming motion on the xy plane and no small angle approximation) textbooks say $\frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)+ m g y = constant$.
However, why is the potential energy $m g y$??
I thought that the total force should be $- \nabla U(x, y)$
However, the potential energy given only accounts for the gravitational force. Where is the term corresponding to the force of the string/massless rod??

I realise that the force from the string (1) does not do work (2) varies in magnitude. However, is the potential energy given formally correct?? If it's not, what would be the correct answer? If it is, what am I misunderstanding?


“Where is the term corresponding to the force of the string/massless rod??” If, as you note, that component does no work—work being a type of energy transfer—and stores no energy, why would it contribute a term to an energy balance?

The equation you give is the sum of kinetic ($\frac{1}{2}m(v_x^2+v_y^2)$) and potential ($mgy$) energy, which is total mechanical energy, which is of course constant. In fact, the actual potential energy ($mgy$) is not constant (because it is linear with $y$ at constant $g$ and $m$), so $-\nabla U=-\nabla(mgy)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(mgy)=mg$.
That is the total force due to the gravitational field, caused by differences of potential in the gravitational field. The mechanical energy term you give does not account for the tension in the string (which should be proportional to a constant and the displacement of the string from rest, if you’re modelling it like you would a spring). You would either need to account for other forces external to the gravitational potential or change the potential to account for the string. I would, personally, do the latter, since I don’t want to model the potential of a spring-like object in two dimensions, but if it’s what’s assigned to you you should.

It's probably safe to assume that in any textbook pendulum problem, if it doesn't say otherwise, then the only energy you have to account for is the gravitational potential energy and the kinetic energy of the pendulum bob. The string/chain/rod-and-pivot from which the bob depends, again if it doesn't say otherwise, are always massless, frictionless, etc. ideals.

@SolomonSlow Thank you both, for the answer and the comment. I'm not a student and I'm not trying to solve something, just get a formal grasp of potential energy. The rod & pivot can indeed be assumed to be ideal, but, even so, $mgh$ does not seem to match the definition of potential energy, that's why I'm asking the question.

Well, as I point out, the gravitational acceleration does equal the gradient of $mgh$.


However, the potential energy given only accounts for the gravitational force. Where is the term corresponding to the force of the string/massless rod??

Because in most cases books analyzes idealized gravity pendulum, which assumes couple of things, such as :

The rod or cord is massless, inextensible and always remains under tension.
The bob is a point mass.
The motion occurs in two dimensions.
The motion does not lose energy to external friction or air resistance.
The gravitational field is uniform.
The support is immobile.

And as such, inextensible string and/or massless rod does not store spring energy $U_{spring} = 1/2~kx^2$, nor it assumes having other types of potential energy, because it's out of the scope of simple gravity pendulum.
Sure, real mechanical pendulum oscillation period depends on many things, couple of them can be :

buoyancy and viscous resistance of the air
the mass of the string or rod
the size and shape of the bob
how bob is attached to the string
flexibility and stretching of the string

If you want  to dig deeper on real pendulum physics I would recommend to start reading the article, by Nelson, Robert; M. G. Olsson (February 1987),- "The pendulum – Rich physics from a simple system" which exactly analyzes couple of these mentioned factors factored-in into real pendulum oscillation period.
Just to note that real pendulum is a very complex model and may have multiple orders of corrections and higher-order oscillation frequency harmonics. So you can spend quite a good amount of time studying these.

The pendulum energy is
$$E=\frac m2\,\left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2\right)+U(x,y)=\rm constant $$
additional the pendulum constraint equation
$$ x^2+y^2=L^2 \quad \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{L^2-y^2}\quad,
\dot x=-{\frac {y{\dot y}}{\sqrt {{L}^{2}-{y}^{2}}}}$$
thus the Potential energy
$$U(x,y)=U(x(y),y)=U(y)$$ if only a function of y
with
$$U(y)=\int F(y)\,dy=\int m\,g\,dy=m\,g\,y$$
where $~F(y)~$ if the gravitation force

In your case the string is not giving a force that can be described by a potential. It is instead a geometric constraint that says $(x,y)$ must be on a circle of sorts. So in some sense your $x$ and $y$ are not independent degrees of freedom. Even without the small angle approximation you can still find the angle $\theta$ as the actual variable that describe the motion, and the effective force on this $\theta$ direction (which is changing as the pendulum swings) will be $-\nabla U(\theta)$

Just to add to the good answers of Agnius Vasiliauskas and controlgroup, for idealized string, we consider it as a constraint in the pendulum movement, not a real physical object. The forces considered to keep the constraints being satisfied are called constraint forces. Despite theses forces are included in force analysis, they usually don't contribute to energy analysis.
Another examples are the normal force due to movement constrained in a plane, inter particle forces to keep a rigid body rigid.
